# Comparing two integers in php

Tags: php, integer, comparison-operators

I need to compare two integers in PHP. I have this example:

```
$a=00713132161838;
$b=713132161838;
```

How can I get this comparison true? I need to delete leading zeros from $a.

I used the number_format function:

```
echo number_format($a,0,"","");
120370289
```

Why this??

Comment: `$a=00713132161838;` A leaing zero when you declare an integer value means that the value is treated as an octal value, not as a decimal [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

leading zero to a number in php is Octal number, and it print `120370289` which is the decimal equivalent of  `00713132161838`. In php there are two kinds of comparison thus,

```
(`00713132161838`==713132161838) // return true
(`00713132161838`===713132161838) // return false and strict comparison
(00713132161838==713132161838) 
// this will never give you true value because 007.....8 is the octal, number first converted to decimal and comparison will be there
```

so you can make use of single/double quote to wrap the numbers and then convert them to decimal integer value  by using `intval` for more information you may need to read [intval function in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: you can accept as an answer if you got your answer ... ?

Answer (score 1):

you can delete leading zero by [ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

example -

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```